# Adding arrow image to tell user that another image is available. android gallery

Tags: android, gallery, image-gallery

I want to add arrow image on right side of gallery item images to show that more images are available.
Is there a way to do that. Can u guys help me out. Hope my question is clear.

Regards!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the following example. this helped me lot to solve the problem.

http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-gallery-widget-example-and-tutorial/

Hope this will help you .

Thanks ,
Rajesh K